# Question/answer improvements regarding grammar/formatting

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, too-minor

During my review activity I found out that there are many questions/answers that really need some grammar fixes / code prettification or at least formatting improvement. I, as well as many others, do my best to improve the quality of content at Stack Overflow, but I noticed that many attempts at such improvements were rejected by suggested edits reviewers.

This is possibly caused by the wrong demarcation line of *too minor* cause, which is explained by

> "this edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post"

Now, as I reached the necessary reputation for reviewing suggested edits I once again acknowledged that.

My idea is that the *too minor* description shouldn't contradict the necessity of accepting grammar/code fixes and such rejections should be discouraged. Though it's true that such edits are in fact minor, we substantially improve the quality of content. That's why I find such edits really useful.

What do you think on this issue?

Comment: Do you have an example of what you think should be accepted, but is rejected as too minor?

Comment: Nothing specific comes to mind, as it is the generalizaion of my personal experience backed up by the cases I was involved in. I think it is not that hard to find such rejections. These concern decapitalized I, conjugations, small code improvements, etc. Note that I don't stress out that the edits are overally rejected, but they *tend to be rejected* by some reviewers.

Comment: Then it's difficult to discuss this. There is a fine line between minor and too minor. And especially since you mention code-edits I fear you might not entirely be in line with what is accepted practice. So some examples would help. If they are easy to find, please go find some.

Comment: I have been seeing this alot, not a fully rejected edit but one person voting to reject it for this reason. I understand that minor are discouraged but shouldnt the criteria be more if it improves the quality of the question vs how major (minor) the edit?

Comment: @Bart, I lately tried to correct a mistake where a non English speaker confused 'piece' with 'peace'. Was rejected, because it was 'too minor'. Ok, no problem. So the mistake remains. Won't kill SO.

Comment: @Greenflow got a link to that one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732583/qobjectstarttimer-timers-cannot-be-started-from-another-thread-without-time. But this is not the only one. Not even sure it is the one I tried to fix. If you search for 'qt' and 'peach' you'll see quite a few of them. Generally I don't care for typos. But wrong words... Some mistakes I find just irritating. Even if they are small.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486002/opencv-calcopticalflowpyrlk-nextpts-with-points-that-have-negative-with-minus. This was the concrete one I tried to fix. Fixed even the code so scrolling wasn't necessary anymore. But it was still not enough. So I gave up. Not **that** important.

Comment: @Greenflow [This is kind of the point though](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6732583/revisions).... [as is this](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18486002/revisions)....

Comment: Agreed, looks **much** better. But I am not a native English speaker myself. So something like that does not come easy to me. And as I said, I don't care for most typos. As long as I understand the question I am happy. But things like 'peace' -> 'piece'. Or 'king' -> 'kind' are another level of ugliness for me. And where is the harm in small edits? Maybe the system could be changed in so far that minor edits are possible, but don't give any rewards.

Comment: @Greenflow The point is that you're asking for a minimum of 3 users to review it for you. Would I have seen your suggestion, then I would have improved upon it with those edits, but still would have rejected yours. If you're going to ask users to review your edits, make them complete. If you can't do that, you might want to hold off on editing until you no longer need the reviews.

Comment: That's exactly what I decided to do: Waiting. With my rate, it won't take too much time anyways. :-D

Answer (score 6):

If you only improve code indentation, when there are other grammar problems, I consider that as too minor.

When you fix a <s>i</s>I, but do nothing else, I consider that as too minor.

If you suggest an edit, fix all the issues the post has. When you do, at least I would accept your suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

A common "too minor" from me is when a suggester sees:

> EVeryone, i need hlp plz this code no work:

and "fixes" it to:

> Everyone, I need help please this code doesn't work:

Because the **real** problem with that sentence is that it exists. It needs to be entirely removed.

Similarly if you fix capitalization, but leave unformatted code, format the code but leave `enter code here`, remove the meta talk (this is my first post, I searched a lot but found nothing, any help will be greatly appreciated) but leave the mis-spellings and poor grammar, or of course fix the spelling while leaving all the meta talk, for all of that I will reject as too minor.

Once you have full edit privileges you can go on a war against i or plz or unformatted code, and ignore other issues in the posts you fix, and the only cost will be that the post gets a little more front-page time than it deserves. But while your edits need to be reviewed, fix **everything** or leave it alone. This often means taking a bit more "big picture" view of the post than just whether or not words are capitalized.

See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/171099/147247 where I assert that edits are accepted not just according to "is the post better now?", which would lead to accepting an edit that changed only one or two things and left eight or ten glaring errors unfixed, but according to "is the post fixed now?" or at least "is the post improved enough to justify a reviewer's time?", which would lead to rejecting the same suggestion.